# Why does `docker image ls` not show the same result as `ctr image ls`?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, docker-daemon, containerdctl

My problem is `docker image ls` shows some Docker images that do not exist in `ctr image ls`.

I check with default namespace and k8s namespace, but my Docker images do not exist in `ctr image ls`.

How can I resolve this problem? When using `docker image load tarfile`, I can't see this image in `ctr image ls`.

Answer (score 3):

Docker doesn't use `containerd` as a image store unless you are running docker daemon with following [configuration](https://docs.docker.com/storage/containerd/):

```
{
  "features": {
    "containerd-snapshotter": true
  }
}
```

So you won't be able to use `ctr` to list images for docker. But if you do enable containerd image store, you have to list images in `moby` containerd namespace:

```
$ ctr -n moby images ls
```